# Zipkin distributed tracing not showing in docker-compose using spring boot

Tags: docker

I am using zipkin distributed tracing with rabbitMQ. But tracing is not showing. When i **RUN QUERY** in zipkin, it does not show anything. Here is my screen

[image]

1. **docker-compose.yaml** file is bellow...'

   ```
   version: '3.7'

   services:

     api-gatway:
       image: mydocker/pocv1-api-gateway:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
       mem_limit: 700m
       ports:
         - "8765:8765"
       networks:
         - account-network
       depends_on:
         - service-registry
         - rabbitmq
       environment:
         EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICEURL.DEFAULTZONE: http://service-registry:8761/eureka
         SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASEURL: http://zipkin-server:9411/
         RABBIT_URI: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
         SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
         SPRING_ZIPKIN_SENDER_TYPE: rabbit

     zipkin-server:
       image: openzipkin/zipkin-slim
       mem_limit: 300m
       ports:
         - "9411:9411"
       networks:
         - account-network
       depends_on:
         - rabbitmq
       environment:
         environment:
         RABBIT_URI: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
       restart: always #Restart if there is a problem starting up

     rabbitmq:
       image: rabbitmq:3-management    
       mem_limit: 300m
       ports:
         - "5672:5672"
         - "15672:15672"
       networks:
         - account-network    

     account-opening:
       image: mydocker/pocv1-account-opening:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
       mem_limit: 700m
       ports:
         - "8081:8081"
       networks:
         - account-network
       depends_on:  
         - postgres    
         - service-registry
         - rabbitmq  
       environment:
         SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/accountdb
         EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICEURL.DEFAULTZONE: http://service-registry:8761/eureka
         SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASEURL: http://zipkin-server:9411/
         RABBIT_URI: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
         SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
         SPRING_ZIPKIN_SENDER_TYPE: rabbit
   networks:
     account-network:
   ```
2. In **application.yml** I use like bellow:

   ```
   spring:
     sleuth:
       sampler:
         probability: 1.0
   ```

I don't know why it is not working. Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You have made a silly mistake that you have included extra environment property in zipkin configuration. you need to remove that line. I faced the same mistake and got resolved in the same way.

```
zipkin-server:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin-slim
    mem_limit: 300m
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"
    networks:
      - account-network
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    environment:
      ***environment:** //remove this line*
      RABBIT_URI: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
      restart: always #Restart if there is a problem starting up
```